# Add padding to select input in chrome?

Tags: html, select, css

The `select` input element for categories in my site http://www.kbay.in , has a padding like so:

```
padding:5px;
```

The padding works fine in Firefox, but in chrome only adds the top and right padding, and it looks kind of awkward, **how can I fix this?**

Comment: Have you tried explicit padding? `padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `select` element has (for some reason) a CSS property as follows:

```
padding-bottom: 0 !important;
```

You need to remove the `!important` otherwise it will not allow it to be overriden.

Comment: thnx ,,wud have never figured it out

Comment: then how did ff overrride it?